jenkins - how to show the Pipeline Graph View in the build page
I've seen the Pipeline Graph View shows ( <div class="PWGx-PipelineGraph-container"> in html ) in official jenkins pipeline as below ( i.e.: https://ci.jenkins.io/job/Core/job/jenkins/job/master/6501/ ):

However, after installed the Pipeline Graph View plugin in my Jenkins, it only shows the Pipeline Overview link in build page, I didn't find anywhere can configure it shows in build page ( instead of sub-link ):

build page


Pipeline Overview


jenkins version:
Jenkins: 2.462.2
OS: Linux - 4.19.12-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
Java: 17.0.12 - Eclipse Adoptium (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
---




In order to enable the graph view outside of Pipeline Overview page, navigate to Manage > Appearance.
There you should see pipeline graph view section.
You can check the option to show in the job page with all the history, or the build page of a specific build.
Thank you for asking that, making me search for the solution! I was looking fir it as well.

thanks a lot !!! you're my savior :)
